# Replace switch statements for child class type

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement, mapping

There is a method that accepts 2 parameters:

```
int selectedClass;
int selectedFunction;
```

Next, there goes 2 switch statements. First of all, it determines child class type using enum:

```
ParentClass p;
switch(selectedClass){
    case (int)ClassTypes.A:
        p = new classA();
        break;
    case (int)ClassTypes.B:
        p = new classB();
        break;
    case (int)ClassTypes.C:
        p = new classC();
        break;
}
```

And it goes on an on for like 50 more statements. Furthermore, there is another switch statement that determines a function:

```
string result;
switch(selectedFunction){
    case (int)FunctionTypes.Func1:
        result = p.function1();
        break;
    case (int)FunctionTypes.Func2:
        result = p.function2();
        break;
    case (int)FunctionTypes.Func3:
        result = p.function3();
        break;
}
```

I did use the search, there are a lot of examples of improving the second switch statement, but not the first one. The 1st question is: how do we determine both child class and function with no switch statements?

2nd: In js I would do something like that:

```
functionsArray[selectedClass][selectedFunction]();
```

Is it possible to implement similar kind of mapping in c#?

Update #1:
I have replaced the 1st switch with the following code:

```
public static Dictionary<ClassTypes, Type> typeDict = new Dictionary<ClassTypes, Type>()
{
    { ClassTypes.A   , typeof(classA) },
    { ClassTypes.B   , typeof(classB) },
    { ClassTypes.C   , typeof(classC) }
};

ParentClass p = (ParentClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeDict[selectedClass]);
```

Comment: Create a common base-class/-interface that all your classes implement and then simply call `myInstance.TheSingleFunction()`?

Comment: As you can see, there already is a base class with virtual functions and I do call functions from a parent class like `p.function3()`. Also, creating an interface won't do by design in that project.

Comment: But instead of having three methods in your base-class, just have one single that all yopur derived classes implement. This way you don´t have to switch on the method, but only on the type.

Comment: probably dictionary style way better - in use then switch, switch is good in small number of cases otherwise readability is bad. Performance is similar - switch became hash based search

Comment: Let me clarify. Every class implements multiple methods. And, of course, we can call either `classA.function1()` or `classA.function2()` or `classA.function3()`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of implementing a dictionary instead of these switch statements?

Comment: You´d have to create a switch anyway in order to **fill** that dictionary. If you have to create different types and need to call different methods, there´s no way to do this automatically, you **have** to do some kind of switch.

Comment: Use reflection if you know for sure that the names are always going to be like ABCD or 1,2,3,4 . Otherwise use Interfaces and try to implement the strategy pattern. Infact Factory.Create can also work

Comment: The first switch could be easily resolved if you pass in the type instead of int and use Activator.CreateInstance<yourType>();

Comment: There is no way I'm using an interface here! In case we will need to add a new method to 1 class in the future, we will have to add it to all 50 classes that implement that interface! Let me use a parent class instead. Names will not be abcd, it's just an example.

Comment: It would be better if you explain how are you getting these values for selectedClass and selectedFunction

Comment: Yes, sure. selectedClass and selectedFunction are being sent from a client machine to our server. We send result as a response.

Comment: @cmos And how do you get the type? You **have** to make some kind of distinction, no matter if you distinguish based upon a type or an int or whatever.

Comment: I have added an answer assuming you can get type names instead of those enums or ints. Even for enums, we can tweak.

Comment: With your update you still have a disiction on an instance of `ClassTypes`, it´s just done withion a map. But if this works for you... just create a second map with the methods to be called in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say I understand the logic that lead you to pick this strange design, but I can think of at least two ways to improve it, providing all the functions you are calling are implemented in the base class (and overriden when needed in the derived classes, of course).

Both solutions are only relevant in case all classes provides a parameter-less constructor and parameter-less functions, and executing the functions does not require further initialization:

**The first solution** would require you to change the method signature, and force the calling method to know the types of the classes so you might not be able to implement it but it involves far less code.

```
ExecuteMethod<TClass>(Func<TClass, string> func) where T: BaseClass, new()
(
    return func(new T());
)
```

And you call it like this:

```
var result = ExecuteMethod<ClassA>(a => a.Function1);
```

**The second solution**
This might be more suitable for your needs:
You will need to create two dictionaries and populate them, like this:

```
private Dictionary<int, Func<ParentClass>> constructors = new Dictionary<int, Func<ParentClass>>()
{
    {1, () => new ClassA()},
    {2, () => new ClassB()}
    // more of the same
};

private Dictionary<int, Func<ParentClass, string>> methods = new Dictionary<int, Func<ParentClass, string>>()
{
    {1, i => i.function1},
    {2, i => i.function2}
    // more of the same
};
```

Then your method can still take two ints and return a string:

```
string DoSomething(int classType, int function)
{
    var instance = constructors[classType].Invoke();
    return methods[function].Invoke(instance);
}
```

Please note that the code is written directly here and not tested, so I might have missed a thing or two, but this is the general idea.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes to your original code, I changed the input parameters to strings, assuming you can directly take names as input. And then instantiating using the first method and invoking using the second. I have added an overload if you want to continue to use the Enum.

```
string selectedClass;
string selectedFunction;

public object GetClassInstanceFromName(string name) 
{
    object type =  Type.GetType($"{this.GetType().Namespace}.{name}";
    return Activator.CreateInstance((Type)type);  
}

public string InVokefunctionByName(object instance,string methName)
{
    return instance.GetType().GetMethod(methName).Invoke(instance, null) as string;     
}

//Overload if you want to continue to use your enum
public object GetClassInstanceFromName(ClassTypes name)
{
    return 
     Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
     "class" +name.ToString());
}

private void Test()
{
   object a = GetClassInstanceFromName(selectedClass);
   Console.WriteLine(InVokefunctionByName(a, selectedFunction));
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Also switching to a better design will always be recommended way.